# How to get NSAffineTransformation from NSGraphicsContext

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I get the context with `[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]`, how do I get the `NSAffineTransform` currently applied to it?

I need this for implementing my own transformation stack where I can perform `push` and `pop` actions just like `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` in OpenGl.

`[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState]` doesn't do it for me because it isn't stackable, or is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is. Save the graphic state before you apply your changes to the context and restore the state after. Each `saveGraphicsState` must be paired with corresponding `restoreGraphicsState` call.

```
// Initial state

[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

[transform1 concat];
// State 1.
//Draw with transform1 concatenated with the current transform of the context

[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

[transform2 set];
// State 2
// draw with transform2 that replaces the transform of the context

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

// now we have State 1 again

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

// We came back to the initial state
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response! I tried this before but it didn't work for some reason. It does now and I'm happy.